# How to escape wild cards in SQL Server Like Clause

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-injection

I am using mssql and sqlsrv libraries (cross platform site) with php and I have had to use a snippet for string sanitation as neither library provides a mysqli_real_escape_string equivalent.

My function is this:

```
public function sanitize($string)
{
  if (is_numeric($string) || $string === 'NULL'        
  {
      return $string;
  }

  $unpacked = unpack('H*hex', $string);
  return '0x' . $unpacked['hex'];
}
```

The function turns strings into hex values that cause the sql statement in the string to be interpreted as a string. I got it from somewhere on stack overflow.

However for `LIKE` queries a string like this `hello%` will interpret the `%` as a wild card even after the hex encoding. In fact, the `%` must be hex-encoded for the like comparison to work.

How do I ensure any user-entered wild card characters are not interpreted as wild card characters?

Example query:

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName FROM Users WHERE UserCode LIKE 'search string'
```

Where 'search string' is a string passed through the sanitize function above.
I always add a `%` to the end of the string before the query but the user may put one at the beginning or middle or use another type of wildcard preventing the query from succeeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally wrote my own function for this and here is what I settled on. Would still appreciate any feedback or better solutions. Am I missing any tokens or special characters in this list?

```
function mssqlLikeEscape($string)
{
  $new_string = preg_replace('/([\[\]%_\^])/', '[$1]', $string);
  return $new_string;
}
```

Example Usage:

```
echo mssqlLikeEscape('A [ in the hand is worth % in the bush.');
```

Results:

```
A [[] in the hand is worth [%] in the bush.
```

Comment: Be aware that you need to be a bit cleverer around the square brackets; if you have a `%` symbol, first it is going to get encoded as `[%]`, then this will get turned into `[[]%]` and finally this will transform to `[[[]]%[]]`. Almost certainly NOT what you want!

Comment: @EdB great point. I completely missed that. I'll have to write a regex for the [ & ] escape so they are performed in the same operation and make it the first check.